# How to force YouTube videos to open in streaming media player instead of default YouTube app?

Tags: youtube, rtsp

I am using HTC Explorer phone, running Android 2.3.5. I use Opera mini and Opera mobile to browse. Whenever I click any YouTube video in the browser to play, automatically the YouTube app opens and starts loading the video but I have a slow connection so I want videos to be played in streaming media player. For any other websites RTSP links it asks me for the app to use.

Earlier it used to ask me for YouTube videos also but now I don't know what settings I have changed. It does not ask now and opens YouTube app. How can I fix this?

Comment: YouTube uses Flash and/or HTML5, not RTSP.  They don't want you accessing videos except through the official website (including embedded videos) or app.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to accomplish this is to use the mobile browser to browse YouTube then when you click on video and it prompts which app to use, click on the browser rather than YouTube app.

[Also this assumes that you have cleared all of the defaults for YouTube and browser.]

As said above, you could always just disable the YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into `Settings -> Applications`
2. Search for `Youtube`
3. Scroll to the `Launch by default` section
4. Tap on `Clear defaults`

Comment: Their are no defaults set for the youtube app.The option "clear defaults" is grayed out.

Comment: Follow the same path and go to youtube and click clear defaults.Or else you just clear your youTubda data by "clear data" button.Try it may but it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

- First Download **[UC Browser](http://wap.ucweb.com/packinfo/english_354/ucbrowser/pf/145?uc_param_str=vepffrbiuplaei&r=main&from=wap-atb-mobile&plang=)**
- Go to YouTube video you want to play via UC browser
- Since UC Browser have its own Built in Video Player it wont redirect you to youtube app
- Now if you want to play it with another video player there is option for that on top right corner called 'Play With'
- Select Video Player and Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

you should try resetting defaults for your browser app from application manager.

go to `settings` > `application manager` > `click your browser app from app list (which ever browser u r using)` > `you are in app info now` > `clear defaults`. this might help u.